# What wait types are associated with SQL Wait Category "Unknown" in Azure SQL database?

Tags: sql, database, azure

I have a query that is already optimized, it is meant to run under few minutes, this partly due to the use of external tables. Sometimes, it runs in few minutes, another time, it could take up to 1 hour, 30 minutes. The execution time is inconsistent.
I had a look at wait stats, the query seems to be spending a long time on Wait Category 'Unknown'. 
Does anybody have any idea about ‘Unknown’ wait category in Azure SQL database or what is causing the inconsistent execution time?